# Camel SQS 2.21 and EndPoint override

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sqs

Is there a method for overriding the queueURL or EndpointURI to listen for messages and to enable using Localstack with Camel AWS 2.21.x? It looks like there was an explicit property added in 2.22, but we're tied to the older version for now.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I see is creating your own client instance and directly use it in the route through the amazonSQSClient parameter.

In that way you should be able to override all the bits you're looking for.